# Animationsm.js Angular failed to compile / was not found

Tags: angular

Since yesterday I'm having this errors when i try to serve my angular project.

```
./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/animations.mjs:533:9-31 - Error: export 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations' (imported as 'ɵsupportsWebAnimations') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)

./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm2015/animations.mjs:533:69-88 - Error: export 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver' (imported as 'ɵCssKeyframesDriver') was not found in '@angular/animations/browser' (possible exports: AnimationDriver, ɵAnimation, ɵAnimationEngine, ɵAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵNoopAnimationDriver, ɵNoopAnimationStyleNormalizer, ɵWebAnimationsDriver, ɵWebAnimationsPlayer, ɵWebAnimationsStyleNormalizer, ɵallowPreviousPlayerStylesMerge, ɵcontainsElement, ɵinvokeQuery, ɵvalidateStyleProperty)
```

Already searched for hours and hours and no solution looks to work with me.

I tried everything from:
Deleting the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` + `npm cache clean --force + npm i`.

Even with `npm i -force`

Deleting and recloning the project from git and do the things above.

Nothing works.

Anyone had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I getting same error and after update Angular dependencies thi's working

(Error)

```
    "@angular/animations": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/material": "^13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~13.1.1",
```

(Working)

```
    "@angular/animations": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/common": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/core": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/material": "^13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.2.2",
    "@angular/router": "~13.2.2",
```

Greetings